# Migrating List workflow to production server in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

We have a list workflow that needs to be taken to production server. But problem is with ListId. Can anyone pl send good link which shows how to modify list ids in XOML file.

Thanks

Comment: Is it a SharePoint Designer Workflow.?

Comment: Let's say it is a designer List workflow. If we have a list workflow through Visual studio then what happens? do we need to change XOML file for List ids?

Answer (score 2):

If you have SPD workflows, please follow the below steps,

1. Open the SharePoint designer and open the source site.
2. Click on the workflows link on the left and then click the workflow you want to move.
3. Click on the ribbon, in "Manage" section, click on "export to Visio button". Now the workflow will be exported to visio format.
4. Now rename the file exported (VWI file) to a "ZIP" file and open it with Windows Explorer. You will find a file named “workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml”
5. Delete "workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml" file.
6. Now rename the archive back to be a VWI file.
7. Now open the destination site (Production site) in SPD.
8. click on the workflows link on the left, then click the import from Visio and browse to the edited VWI file. This will allow you to re-associate your workflow as if it was created or exported from Visio rather than the designer while preserving any development made in the workflow it self.

Hope this approach might help you for migrating.

If you find the above answer is useful, please mark it as answer.

Please feel free to unmark answer if does not resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If it is Visual Studio workflow what happens to that?

Comment: Great post, very detailed and works straight away, thanks a lot.